# Closure of a singleton in a specific topology

Tags: general-topology

I ran into a problem while solving the following exercice:

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, denoted $\varepsilon$, and with the following topology aswell:
> $$ \tau=\left \{ U\subseteq \mathbb{R} : (U\in\varepsilon)\wedge(\forall x \in U, x^2 \in U  \right \} $$
>
> 1. Does $\varepsilon$ and $\tau$ are the same topology?
> 2. Define the interior of the following subsets: $A=[-1,1]$, $B=(-\infty,1)$, $C=(1/2,+\infty)$ and $D=[-2,-1]$.
> 3. Finally, define the closure of the singleton $\left \{ x \right \}$, for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

So, here's my work:

For part 1, we can easily see that $\tau$ is weaker than $\varepsilon$ by definition of $\tau$: every open set of $\tau$ is open in $\varepsilon$. But they are not equal since, for example, $(1,3)$ is open in $\varepsilon$ and not in $\tau$, since $2\in(1,3)$ but $2^2=4\notin(1,3)$.

For part 2, I've found that $int(A)=(-1,1)$ which is indeed an open set in $\tau$ since it verify the conditions. Thus, we can define $int(B)=(-1,1)$, $int(C)=(1,+\infty)$ and $int(D)=\emptyset$.

But, I've a bit more troubles defining the closure of a singleton in this topology. From my understanding, the closure of a singleton would be equal to itself (in this topology): let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\left \{ x \right \}$ is indeed closed in our topology, because $\mathbb{R}\backslash\left \{ x \right \}=(-\infty,x)\cup(x,+\infty)$ which is indeed an open set in our topology (because it is an union of two standard open sets, and we can verify that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\left \{ x \right \}, y^2\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\left \{ x \right \}$). By definition of the closure of a set, since the singleton is closed, it is equal to his closure.

Is my work correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for $x>0, x \neq 1$ we have $x= {\sqrt x}^2 \not\in \mathbb R \setminus \{x\}$, hence $\mathbb R \setminus \{ x \}$ is not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$

Is meaningless? Or maybe it's meaningful but it is satisfied by no $x$. At any rate, don't conflate your variables, give things a new name.

I disagree that $\forall y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ we have $y^2\in\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$. What if $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$?

Continue the exercise by doing the following:

- Show that if $x$ is nonpositive or $x=1$, then $\{x\}$ is closed
- Show that if $x$ is positive but not equal to $1$, then $\{x\}$ is not closed; prove that: $$\overline{\{x\}}=\{x,1,-1\}\cup\{x^{2^{-n}}:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{-x^{2^{-n}}:n\in\Bbb N\}$$

Comment: looks good :) +1

Comment: wait, we forgot that it should also be closed according to the euclidean topology, right? then I think we have to add $\{\pm 1\}$ to your $\overline{\{x\}}$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: It was indeed a mistake, I meant $\forall y$, sorry. I think I understand it now. I'll try to work on it later. Thanks for your wise observation!

Comment: @Targon Wow, I have made a lot of errors just now. You're right, $\pm1$ requires inclusion

Comment: @FShrike Now I am a bit confused on why we need to add $\pm 1$ to our closure in the second case? Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @tmsgm If $x>0$ then $\lim_{a\to0}x^a=1$. In particular $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^{-n}}=1$

Comment: @FShrike Fair enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @tmsgm np. ; ) you should thank targon for catching my carelessness

Comment: Thank @Targon :) Anyway, I'll try to do a formal proof and I might come back if I still have some gray areas, but you two provided me sufficient tips.